# Code not rendering correctly on github.io

Tags: angularjs, github, jekyll

I am trying to put some code on my blog on github.io. It is pixyll theme on jekyll.

An example of the code is

````html
```
<!-- Add some model -->
<input type="text" ng-model="hello-model"></input> 
<!-- And show that up -->
<h1>{{hello-model}}</h1>

```
````

However, when it shows up on the blog. it is showing up without the {{ }}.

```html
<!-- Add some model -->
<input type="text" ng-model="hello-model"></input> 
<!-- And show that up -->
<h1></h1>
```

Can someone help me add the {{}} back in the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because both AngularJS and Jekyll use {{ }} (binding and templates respectively).

You may solve your issue by using `ng-bind`. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) for the corresponding docs.
Essentially it would look like

```
<h1 ng-bind="hello-model"></h1>
```